# Intent parando o Aplicativo no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-intent

Estou com um problema com o **Intent**, uma coisa que era para ser simples está me causando problemas...

Estou tentando criar um segundo botão para **chamar uma outra tela**, porém assim que eu adiciono o seguinte código o aplicativo para:

```
mAnaliseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.custom_view_analiseDetalhada);
        mAnaliseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Books.this, AnaliseScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Existem (**4**) telas criadas em meu aplicativo quais são respectivamente:

> - ActivitySplashScreen
> - AboutScreen
> - Books
> - AnaliseScreen
> - A tela Books.class é aonde abre a camera do usuário.

A **ActivitySplashScreen** inicia, chamando automaticamente o **AboutScreen**. No **AboutScreen** existe um botão para chamar o **Books** e no **Books** assim que detecta a **ImageTarget** abre um **Bookzinho** com os dados e um botão para chamar a **AnaliseScreen**.

Porém caso eu adicione o código acima, assim que eu clicar no Botão na tela **AboutScreen** para iniciar o **Books** o **Aplicativo para de funcionar**, o interessante é que **já existe um botão dentro do Books e ele funciona perfeitamente e não dá este tipo de erro**.

**Segue os códigos abaixo(Caso seja preciso eu encaminho os que vocês pedirem):
OBS: POSTAREI OS CÓDIGOS ATRAVÉS DE UM LINK, POIS OS MESMOS ESTÃO PASSANDO O LIMITE MÁXIMO DE CARACTERS DO FORUM.**

> - **Books.java** https://paste.ofcode.org/c8TsPaY4bVx99c6yGCrtF
> - **AboutScreen.java** https://paste.ofcode.org/HJX4v6hfvifyXXNkD7jxe2
> - **AnaliseScreen.java** https://paste.ofcode.org/jRww8Sfak6XrhQLciVd67x

- **about_screen.xml**

  > https://paste.ofcode.org/Cbj4zFiX6dmqQ5zJPGNvJV 
  >   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- **analise_screen.xml**

  > https://paste.ofcode.org/jRww8Sfak6XrhQLciVd67x
- **book_data_layout.xml**

  > https://paste.ofcode.org/HfpDRdWy2jX2QSF3i2fQqz 
  >   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- **camera_overlay_books.xml**

  > https://paste.ofcode.org/bYyz8kZLXyUJjRpwYebtUi 
  >   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- **AndroidManifest.xml**

  > https://paste.ofcode.org/n6CMarNcDQB2CeFv8VPDc
- ** ERRO **:

> 05-29 16:23:38.002 21258-21258/com.vuforia.samples.Books
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.vuforia.samples.Books, PID: 21258
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.vuforia.samples.Books/com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Books.Books}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2584)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1505)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
>                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at
>   com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Books.Books.startLoadingAnimation(Books.java:523)
>                                                                                  at com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Books.Books.onCreate(Books.java:343)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2537)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1505) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)

Comment: Que erro dá? Tem a Activity *Books* declarada no AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @ramaral , esqueci de postar o AndroidManifest. Acabei de postar ali na pergunta, da uma olhada lá por gentileza.

Comment: Você pode ver o motivo porque esta ocorrendo esse erro no log.

Comment: Tenho a impressão que o _finish()_ depois do _startActivity(i)_ fecha a activity mãe. Tenta comentar.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo , Coloquei o erro na minha publicação.

Comment: @EdsonFSantos , tentei retirar o finish(); dos dois button e depois de um button só aconteceu a mesma coisa.

Comment: E quando você clica na primeira linha em vermelho do erro. Para onde ele te leva nos fontes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua Activity Books não está inflando o layout book_data.xml (que contém o custom_view_analiseDetalhada), então quando você tenta inicializar a variável mAnaliseButton com o findViewById(), ele retorna nulo para essa variável (porque não encontrou o id passado como parâmetro) e com isso dá o erro que você postou, de tentar associar o listener (setOnClickListener) num objeto nulo.

O outro botão funciona (estou imaginando que seja o mBackButton) porque você infla o layout apropriado antes de tentar setar o listener para o mesmo.

Comment: entendi.. Como eu faço para descobrir qual é o layout .java certo ? Porque isso que estou utilizando é um sdk do vuforia e não fui eu que criei algumas coisas como o layout.

Comment: O layout é o book_data.xml que postei na minha resposta, pelo menos acho que é, pois foi o que eu vi que contem o id que você quer chamar no seu código. Tenta inflar o layout da mesma forma que foi feito para o mBackButton no método startLoadingAnimation().

Answer (score 1):

Amigo , tente desta forma , retirei o finish ()

```
        mAnaliseButton = (Button) 
        findViewById(R.id.custom_view_analiseDetalhada);
        mAnaliseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Books.this, AnaliseScreen.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Comment: eu já tentei inserir sem o finish. Mas mesmo assim acontece o erro.

Comment: Recomendo que de uma olhada neste link

Comment: http://www.androidpro.com.br/intents/

Comment: Vê se vai agora , coloquei no setOnclick o New View.OnClickListener

Comment: Thiago deu certo?

Comment: utilizei o conhecimento do Márcio Oliveira. Mas obrigado.